# Trigger a script with live command line output

Tags: python, command-line, cmd, raspberry-pi3

I have a  python code which prints output to the commandline in every second. It prints out "alarm" or "test" according to the microphone output.

I want to write a shell script which triggers another script according to the command line output. Do you know how can I implement it?

I want it to record sounds when the sensor prints "alarm" or "test".

Thanks in advance

Comment: My suggestion will be, redirect your command line output to text file. Read that text file line by line, if its "alarm" or "test" execute the script you want.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what kind of shell script or describe how the python code is running.

If you could pipe the output of the python code to, say a ksh script?, then it's just a matter of doing something like this:

```
mycode.py|myscript.ksh
```

And in your ksh script doing something like

```
#!/bin/ksh
until [[ signal == "abort" ]]
  read signal
  do
      case signal in
               test)
                   printf "test\n"
                   ;;
               alarm)
                   printf "alarm\n"
                   ;;
      esac
  done
```

This being said, I do wonder why you don't just handle whatever the script is doing in your python program.

Comment: I'm using a python vu-meter program which is not written by me, when i run it, it will print vu-meter value to the linux command line. Each new measurement is written to the last line etc.
So in basic im not able to edit this program. 
My purpose is to run arecord code when high volume is detected. 
I know the vu meter output, i know the arecord code but i do not know how to pipe them with condition